# How to append a list of dataframes by removing header from all list and keeping only first header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes

li = [df1, df2,..]

All the dataframes in the list have common headers. I am appending the list of dataframes into a single df as follows:

```
path ="..."
all_files=glob.glob(path+"*.csv")
all_files
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df=pd.read_csv(filename,index_col=None,header=None)
    li.append(df)
```

However, will there be multiple headers after appending the list of dfs into one? If so, How to keep only the first header and remove the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Use pd.concat()
For more info you can refer
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concat in loop itself.

Let's assume csv1 looks like.

```
     Ref   tim
0    1    mow
1    2    pak
2    3    bow
3    4  tring
```

Let's assume csv2 looks like.

```
     Ref   tim
0    1    mow
1    2    pak
2    3    bow
3    4  tring
```

Read files uisng glob and concat at once as follows.

```
path =r"..."
all_files=glob.glob(path)
df = (pd.read_csv(each) for each in all_files)
df= pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Gives #

```
   Ref    tim
0    1    mow
1    2    pak
2    3    bow
3    4  tring
4    1    mow
5    2    pak
6    3    bow
7    4  tring
```